# Does Standard Logic Apps support multiple triggers

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard

does anyone know if Standard Logic Apps support multiple triggers? I was building a Standard one in the portal and as soon as I added a second trigger to it, it says "You cannot use this trigger as an action". I know the consumption models support multiple triggers. So just wondering if it is because of wrong settings at the time creating the resource, or permission, or other things.

I tried adding a second trigger both in the Code View and Visualizer. I was expecting that to work, but no.

Answer (score 0):

> Does Standard Logic Apps support multiple triggers

Standard Logic app Supports Multiple workflow, not the multiple trigger concept as per below analysis.

[image]

In above image you can clearly see that you can add a new workflow.

The below image says that you add multiple triggers. This is a limitation in Logic App I am facing. To use ,more than one trigger you need to create another workflow for it

[image]

Even when i tried to change using code it says `expected 1`:

[image]

But [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-limits-and-config?tabs=consumption,azure-portal#workflow-definition-limits) says 10 are possible by doing it in code view or arm template not the designer. And from code view too i am unable to do, For this you can open a feature request or support request.